# Add to cart success message

Tags: addtocart, store-view, translate

```
    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__(
    'You added product %1 to the <a href="%2">comparison list</a>.',
    $block->getData('product_name'),
    $block->getData('compare_list_url')),
    ['a']
);
```

I have Swedish store view as well and this text is not translated in to Swedish How can I  translate it into swedish

Answer (score 0):

you can do this way..

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/i18n/sv_SE.csv

```
"You added product %1 to the <a href=""%2"">comparison list</a>.","You added product %1 to the <a href=""%2"">comparison list</a>."
```

Right side you can add your translation word and after **clear cache**

Comment: No It did not worked for me

Comment: @HafsaZulfiqar first you check where is your language file then add it then cache clear or run deploy command

Comment: I have child the,e and added in i18n/sv_SE.csv but when I run deploy command then the changes are not reverting and not even deployed in pub folder